# Removing layer and exporting mapbook into PDF?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am new Python.

I need to write a script that turns off a layer (and removes it from the legend, which it would probably do automatically since that box is checked in legend properties) and then I need to export the map book.

I need to do this many times, so it'd be nice to have a script.

Heres what I have. It runs and gives me no errors and also doesn't give me a pdf...

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

'# Local Variables

Goldendale = r"\\WSBS\Company\PROJECTS\2013\12 - December\131226 - Goldendale SMP\GIS\Data\Shapefiles\goldendale_UGA.shp"

'# Remove Goldendale

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(
    r"\\ws01\Company\PROJECTS\2012\12 - December\121201 - Klickitat SMP\GIS\MXD\InventoryMapfolio\10_KlickitatSMP_FloodplainFloodways.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)
names = [Goldendale]

for layers in layers:
    if layers.name in names:
        layers.visible = False

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

'# Save

mxd.save()

'# Export to Mapbook to PDF

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,r"\\ws01\Company\PROJECTS\2012\12 - December\121201 - Klickitat SMP\GIS\PDF\InventoryMapfolio\Revised_20160812\10_KlickitatSMP_FloodplainFloodways.pdf", "ALL")
```

What would I need to change in order for me to get a combined PDF without the layer?

Comment: Is Data Driven Pages enabled?

Comment: @Midavalo - Yes, Data Driven Pages is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main mistake is that:

```
for layers in layers:
    if layers.name in names:
        layers.visible = False
```

should be:

```
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name in names:
        layer.visible = False
```

but I'm not sure why you have quotes around the two parts below:

```
'# Local Variables

Goldendale = r"\\WSBS\Company\PROJECTS\2013\12 - December\131226 - Goldendale SMP\GIS\Data\Shapefiles\goldendale_UGA.shp"

'# Remove Goldendale
```

and

```
'# Save

mxd.save()

'# Export to Mapbook to PDF
```

You also seem to be looking for a layer named `r"\\WSBS\Company\PROJECTS\2013\12 - December\131226 - Goldendale SMP\GIS\Data\Shapefiles\goldendale_UGA.shp"` (which is what you have your `Goldendale` variable set to) in your Table of Contents.  Perhaps you meant to set your list named `names` to `["Goldendale"]` rather than `[Goldendale]`